# Payment modules not stored in VirtueMart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a huge problem with my VirtueMart. I try to develop a new payment module for it. The main problem is that no matter how I do it VirtueMart seems to refuse to let me store the plug-in in the database and also it refuses to let me choose it as a payment method.

I have disabled all other "countries" except the one that the module is written for. I have followed all guides on [joomla mastery](http://joomlamastery.com/). I am convinced that my constructor is correct according to the scarce documentation I have found. I have even copy/pasted an existing payment module and changed all names for the database to something different so I can see if it's created and it's a no-go.

I am starting to get desperate. Does anyone have a good virtuemart developer guide? Do I need to turn some flags on (the flag to update/write to database is on in joomla and virtuemart) or off? How can I programatically FORCE VirtueMart to actually listen to what it say should work in all documentations I've found?

Comment: check this http://joomlamastery.com/6-virtuemart-development-build-custom-shipment-payment-plugin-101-part-2

Comment: It seems as if it dissallowed names of the plugin containing _ or camelcasing in the name of the plugin (my plugin name was two Words, and I tried both, when I just used a three letter abbriviation of the two words and pulled them together, it was ok.